# .Net Core Web Api project Can't Debug with Visual studio code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Created a .net Core Web Api Project in Visual Studio code. I wanted to Debug the app  so I Added the Configuration as "Attach to Local .Net Core Console App".after that i pressed debug button. then it asked me to attach the app.but my app didn't appear in the dropdown. i tried several things but  didn't work anything.I found that the configuration settings stored in the "launch.json" file and I cleared the configurations array from the launch.json and re added from the add configuration button. but didn't work anything yet. the problem is when i try to attach to the process of my app is not showing to attach. Please help me to fix the issue. I have attached some images and the project.
[image: launch.Json File]
[image: debuger window where i should attach the process]

[project](https://jumpshare.com/v/O0cr4HfxQTa0WzkrNU5Q) 
Thanks.

Comment: Edit `launch.json` and change `program` to point to your actual assembly file path.

Comment: Thanks lex . it is working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied from comment.

VSCode's C# extension usually generates a `launch.json` file, but it does not work immediately, as its `program` attribute requires your edit so as to point to the correct executable.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Your `.vscode` folder should include a `launch.json` file.
If it's not there, simply close vs code and open it again, make sure you are in the project directory (from the Terminal).
Then a vs code pop up will appear from the bottom right telling you it can't detect a `launch.json` and it will ask you whether it should create one for you. Click yes, then press `F5` and the API server will run in debug mode.